# Why does the clone method goes backwards for Array in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs

I am reading ExtJS 4 source code. Here is a piece from the clone method. Why does the clone method goes backwards for Array in EntJS 4?

```
    if (type === '[object Array]') {
        i = item.length;

        clone = [];

        while (i--) {
            clone[i] = Ext.clone(item[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating backwards means they don't need to add an extra comparison to `item.length` or otherwise store it separately. They only need one variable, `i`.